# How can I know when the available options in a select box changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a select box on my page where the options dynamically change:

```
<select size="6" multiple="multiple" >
    <option value="1">Id</option>
    <option value="2">Subject</option>
    <option value="3">Status</option>
    <option value="4">Assignment</option>
    <option value="5">LastCreatedBy</option>
</select>
```

When it changes I would like to refresh some text elsewhere on the screen based on the displayed options.

The problem is I can't seem to find an event that is thrown for when an option is added or deleted.

How may I be notified when the number of options in a select box changes.

Comment: you added those options in js right?. can't you just call a function after that?

Comment: What causes the options to be added or deleted? (Hint: Your code. That's the "event")

Comment: @Amit - yeah unfortunately, I can't actually mess with that. It's in multiple places and it's generated by a custom ASP.NET webforms control which I can't modify and no access to the events.

Comment: @Diskdrive - luckily for you, T.J Crowder gave you a great answer (You should accept it). But - I'd look at the ASP.NET control for more information. That's the source of the event and if it's properly designed it should generate events / hooks for you to use. What you're describing is like sitting under the faucet waiting to get wet in order to know the knob was turned (Awkward, and poorly designed). All that said, sometimes you have no alternative and you have to get wet :-)

Comment: @Amit - yeah for sure, testing it right now. Concerned about it not working on ie 8 which unfortunately, my app is run on :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch the `select` element for changes to its contents:

```js
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
  snippet.log("Changed");
});
ob.observe(document.getElementById("foo"), {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true
});
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("foo").options.add(new Option("Hi"));
}, 100);
```

```html
<select id="foo"></select>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

`MutationObserver` is [well-supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) except for IE, which didn't get them until IE11. But IE supported the [old mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events); you can find shims/polyfills that use the old events to provide the new interface (or just use the old events directly if `typeof MutationObserver === "undefined"`). I don't know whether the old events were fired by IE when you change the options in a select, though, you'll need to check.

As a last resort if there is no `MutationObserver` and mutation events don't work, poll. Polling every 50ms or so shouldn't have any significant impact on the performance of your page.

Comment: thanks, i ended up just using the polling option. I have to support IE 8 and the old mutation events seem to be outdated. So it's probably easier for me to do just polling and then later on move to the MutationObserver when we end support

Comment: @Diskdrive: Probably, yeah. Yes, the old mutation events were apparently a massive performance problem for engines, hence `MutationObserver`. (I don't know the details of that...)